# Calling a function a second time with only slight changes

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a function called get_next_train:

```
def get_next_train(params):
    res =requests.get(base, params=params)
    parsed_json = res.json()

    #Zeiten aus parsed_json extrahieren
    time_strings = [d["from"]["prognosis"]["departure"]
        for d in parsed_json["connections"]]

    #String, um Zeiten in time_strings nach ISO 8601 zu parsen
    iso_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"

    # Time Strings zu datetime Objekten konvertieren
    times = [datetime.strptime(ts, iso_format) 
        for ts in time_strings if ts is not None]

    # Checken, ob times leer sind
    if not times:
    return None # CHANGE: return None if no times found

    #Zeitzone der ersten zeit in Times speichern
    tz = times[0].tzinfo

    #jetztige Zeit mit Zeitzone tz, Mikrosekunden löschen
    nowtime = datetime.now(tz).replace(microsecond=0)


    time = min(t for t in times[0:3] if t > nowtime) # CHANGE: use min
    return time, time - nowtime
```

I want it to be executed twice: The first time just the way it is now. But the second time,  time_strings should be this:

```
time_strings = [d["from"]["departure"]
    for d in parsed_json["connections"]]
```

I've tried countless ways of doing it but failed every time. The most common error was:

name 'parsed_json' is not defined.

I could of course just copy paste this whole code and change the bit I need to, but is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: please add the code that calls the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general principle of factoring is to keep common code the same and turn differences into function parameters.

The difference between the two versions of the function is which subelement is extracted in the list comprehension. We can abstract the difference out into a function:

```
def get_next_train(params, select_element):
    res = requests.get(base, params=params)
    parsed_json = res.json()

    # extract times from parsed_json
    time_strings = [select_element(d)
        for d in parsed_json["connections"]]

    ...
```

Now you can call

```
get_next_train(params, lambda d: d["from"]["prognosis"]["departure"])
get_next_train(params, lambda d: d["from"]["departure"])
```

---

Alternatively we could have used

```
    time_strings = [select_element(d["from"])["departure"]
        for d in parsed_json["connections"]]
```

in the function and

```
get_next_train(params, lambda x: x["prognosis"])
get_next_train(params, lambda x: x)
```

in the call, which removes all redundancy but is a lot harder to understand and to generalize IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate what stays the same. Encapsulate what varies.

You could define two different functions to get time strings. One to get prognosis:

```
def time_strings_from_prognosis(json):
    return [d["from"]["prognosis"]["departure"]
            for d in json["connections"]]
```

and another to get other:

```
def time_strings_other(json):
    return [d["from"]["departure"]
            for d in json["connections"]]
```

Then pass the function to get time strings to your original function:

```
def get_next_train(params, get_time_strings):
    ...
    time_strings = get_time_strings(parsed_json)
```

And call it as:

```
get_next_train(params, time_strings_from_prognosis)
```

or:

```
get_next_train(params, time_strings_other)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a second parameter when you call the function:

```
def get_next_train(params, flag):
res =requests.get(base, params=params)
parsed_json = res.json()

#Zeiten aus parsed_json extrahieren
if (flag):
    time_strings = [d["from"]["prognosis"]["departure"]
        for d in parsed_json["connections"]]
else:
    time_strings = [d["from"]["departure"]
        for d in parsed_json["connections"]]        

#String, um Zeiten in time_strings nach ISO 8601 zu parsen
iso_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"

# Time Strings zu datetime Objekten konvertieren
times = [datetime.strptime(ts, iso_format) 
    for ts in time_strings if ts is not None]

# Checken, ob times leer sind
if not times:
return None # CHANGE: return None if no times found

#Zeitzone der ersten zeit in Times speichern
tz = times[0].tzinfo

#jetztige Zeit mit Zeitzone tz, Mikrosekunden löschen
nowtime = datetime.now(tz).replace(microsecond=0)


time = min(t for t in times[0:3] if t > nowtime) # CHANGE: use min
return time, time - nowtime
```

Here the 'flag' parameter is just a boolean but it can be whatever you want...

Comment: Your solution works, but it's less attractive because 1) you still have some repetition in the `if` / `else` part itself, and 2) the calls now look like `get_next_train(params, True); get_next_train(params, False)` and you have no idea what that boolean parameter means unless you read through the function source.

Comment: Hmm, you're absolutely right... I look at your answer and yes, it is better than mine and also more clean and without repetitions